# How to Test google in app billing v3 in sandbox mode in android

Tags: android

I want to test in app real product using google inapp billing v3. 
Is there any way we can test real product in sandbox mode like iOs by paying dummy payment.

Comment: There is facility to add email address for testing purpose. see the link http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test